# How to draw signal using different colour in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I have plotted the following graph:

[image]

The graph includes three different signals (i.e. 1, 2, and 3). This signal represents the data of the first column of the attached file (Plot_Data.csv). I’m wondering if we can draw each signal part in different colour. For example, black colour for part 1, red colour for part 2, etc.

[Plot_Data.csv](https://ufile.io/nk7hk)

Comment: The solution to your task will have several steps: reading in the data, plotting the data, and styling the plot appropriately. Refine your question to show which step you need help with and what you've tried already on your own.

Comment: Please include the code you used to plot the graph.

Comment: thank you mate :) the problem is already solived

Answer (score 2):

This a simple example to do so. I created a sin signal of 1000 samples, blue colored first 300 sample, red colored the next 300 samples and the rest samples are black

```
x=0.1:0.1:100;
y=sin(x);
plot(x(1,1:300),y(1,1:300),'b',x(1,300:600),y(1,300:600),'r',x(1,600:end),y(1,600:end),'k')
```

[image]

Similarly for your plot

```
a=xlsread('plot_data.csv');
plot([1:9.821e3],a(1:9.821e3,1),'r',[9.821e3:2.7e4],a(9.821e3:2.7e4,1),'b',[2.7e4:size(a(:,1),1)],a(2.7e4:end,1),'k')
```

[image]